# CSS select :not the child elements of the parent element

Tags: css

What's the right syntax for using :not selector for child elements?

Example: All elements should be invisible except the child elements of parent. I tried :not(.parent childs) but it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Your specific case in a fiddle would be nice. But here's a fiddle where every child of body gets a red background except `p` elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/dm0gm6cc/1/

Comment: I need to hide all elements but not the descending elements of parent. if the (grand)parent element of the parent element is not displayed, all descending elements wouldn't too. therefore I need to descent in the dom tree thought like this:

:not(.grandparents > parent childs) {
 display: none;
}

Comment: Please make a fiddle with your html. It's very hard to read from pure text what you are trying to hide and what not. If I go purely by your text, it sounds like to want to hide and element and show it's children. If that's the case then that's impossible. 
But this could be mis-communication. 
Making a use case in a fiddle wil most likely clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

:not(selector)
:not(p)
    Selects every element that is not a

element

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is as follows:
**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div class="parent inner">
    master parent
    <div>
        parent
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        child
    </div>
    <div>
        parent
    </div>
    <div>
        parent
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Use the following command to select the child rows:

```
div:not(.child) > div.parent {color:red; display: block !important; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/zsma7mv8/1/)

And for all elements should be invisible except the child elements of parent:

```
div:not(.parent) {display: none; }
.inner > div {color:red; display: block !important;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/zsma7mv8/2/)